# how can I check if a particular item is clicked with .blur() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an autocomplete dropdown that appears when a user starts typing in a textbox (I'm using jquery mobile but I don't think that's important to my problem). I want to be able to hide the whole dropdown list when a user clicks anywhere on the page. However, I don't want to hide the dropdown when a user actually clicks on the dropdown itself.

Is there a way I could catch the click event in order to know what was clicked?

Here's my blur function:

```
//hide autocomplete when dropdown is not clicked
$("#search-div input").blur(function () {
    $("#autocomplete-list").hide();
});
```

I was thinking of somehow putting an if statement in my blur function. Here's my pseudo code:

```
if( dropdown clicked)
{
    run code to take text from dropdown and place in textbox
}
else
{
    hide dropdown
}
```

Would it be possible to know whether my dropdown is clicked or something else is clicked while in my blur function? When I debug my javascript I'm only seeing an event that's related to the textbox doing the blur()

**Edit:**

Here is a function I'm using to handle when the dropdown is clicked:

```
$( document).on( "click", "#autocomplete-list li", function() {
    var selectedItem = event.target.innerHTML;
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input').val(selectedItem);
    $('#autocomplete-list').hide();
    runSearchQuery();
});
```

Comment: Blur isn't really what you are looking for.

Comment: A [workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/0fuLo22b/).

Comment: @Omar your workaround was perfect. However, could you explain your solution in an answer? I would like to know how the setTimeout function is used exactly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for any click, not just a blur, and then check what the clicked element was. `e.currentTarget` gives you what was clicked.

```
var clickHandler = function(e) {
  if ($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('dropdown')) {
    // do nothing
  } else {

    // Make sure you unregister your event every
    // time the dropdown is hidden.
    $(window).off('click', clickHandler);
    // hide
  }
}

// When the dropdown comes down, register an event on the whole page.
$(window).on('click', clickHandler);
```

Comment: When I debug, the if/else is only executed when I first click inside the textbox the first time. But the event does not fire after that. Could you give me a tip on how to debug this?

Comment: Are you re-registering the event (my last line) every time the dropdown opens?

Comment: I guess not. that line only executes on page load, but never again. Why would this happen? thanks

Comment: You need to add code that registers it. Getting a functional autocomplete is going to take a lot more than 8 lines of code - I'm not showing you how to complete the whole thing - just pointing you in the right direction of your original question.

Comment: I already have code to handle when my dropdown list is clicked, please see my edit. However, I'm still having issues re-registering the click in order to know if a click is not the dropdown. thanks

Comment: is there a way I could combine my function with your suggestion? thanks!

Comment: well, I was able to get somewhere by actually just removing the line where we unregister the click. I'm not entirely sure what the implications of this would be though

Comment: It will probably work, but it is bad practice as now the Window will keep listening. If you have two typeaheads, it means you register it twice, things start getting messy.

Comment: Do you have a typeahead.open function or something? Like, whenever you draw the dropdown part, that is when you should register the click handler in a new unit of time.